# How to show line items having null values using DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

We have two tables

Table A =  
`Dates = CALENDAR(date(2023,1,1),TODAY())`

**Edits** ADDED LINE ITEM MANGO
Table B =

[image]

Relationship between columns:
[image]

Date joined to Date from Data table, One to Many.

DAX to get ROI

```
ROIZ = 
VAR V1 = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Spent]),ALLSELECTED(Dates[Date]),ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Type]))
VAR V2 = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Returns]),ALLSELECTED(Dates[Date]),ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Type]))
return divide(V2,V1,0)
```

When I select January, I get the following:

[image]

which is wrong, pear should show 8 instead of 18, **and Kiwi is missing.**

When I select February, I get the following:

[image]

which is wrong, pear should show nothing or 0

---

Expected Output: (January)
[image]

OR

February

[image]

---

You will get the Output just by using the below code

```
 roi =  divide(sum(data[spent]),sum(data[return]))
```

However, it won't give you the output which needs to include the **Kiwi line item for January** and **Mango line item for February**.

---

**NEW EDIT THAT INCLUDES NEW DAX THAT I TRIED WHICH GIVES CLOSER RESULTS TO EXPECTED OUTPUT. The below section is Added 3/29 10 AM PST, the above section was the original question**

```
ROIZ = 
VAR V1 = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Spent]),ALLSELECTED(Dates[Date]),ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Type]))
VAR V2 = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Returns]),ALLSELECTED(Dates[Date]),ALLEXCEPT(Data,Data[Type]))
return divide(V2,V1,0) +0
```

Added +0 at the end, which gives a closer output format to expected output, but the results for Pear are wrong, which should've been 8 for January and 0 for February.

**Jan Output**
[image]

**Feb Output**
[image]

Comment: You say that *Dates* and *Data* are joined on the *Date* column, though your sample for *Data* does not include a *Date* column. Can you amend and repost?

Comment: Hi Jos, I have updated the Table B to show the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this measure:

```
ROIZ =
IF (
    MAX ( Data[Type] )
        IN VALUES ( Data[Type] ),
    DIVIDE (
        SUM ( Data[Returns] ),
        SUM ( Data[Spent] )
    ) + 0,
    BLANK ()
)
```

Comment: Hi Jos, I tried this, but it still doesn't display the Kiwi line Item. which has a date '1/25/2023'.

Comment: Suggest you replace your blanks with zeroes in the source data. Alternatively, I could modify the DAX so that all fruits are returned in all cases, though with a zero for ROIZ where applicable.

Comment: We can assume that Spent and Return data will remain blank until the user(seller, buyer) enters that information onto the website which is tied to the database. and we need to use DAX to fix this. I have tried another DAX, I will update it in the Question and it will be in the section titled EDITS in red.

Comment: Hi Jos, added my new DAX, which gives an output closer to the expected output. also added a new Line Item Mango to test results for February.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Apart from the issue with blanks, my solution gives correct results everywhere as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi Jos, Yes, the question is about getting Power BI to display the blank information along with the DAX calculation as shown in the expected output.  The output from your code gives the same information as the output of this => ROI = DIVIDE(sum(Data[Returns]), sum(Data[Spent])). This shows the total as 26 for February instead of 6 and doesn't show the line item with blanks

Comment: Re 26 total for February, that's correct, no? Your basic calculation is to divide Sum of Returns by Sum of Spent, is it not? So at the total level that's 650/25=26. Or are you saying you want that calculation to only apply to the filtered rows and to be overwritten with something else at the total level?

Comment: P.S. Your post includes no mention of this new request, i.e. to override the aggregation at the total level with a different calculation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252857/discussion-between-stackone-and-jos-woolley).

Comment: Hi Jos, Moving the discussion to chat. Oh yeah, my bad, 26 shows the correct information. However, the output can be got by simply using this DAX ROI = DIVIDE(sum(Data[Returns]), sum(Data[Spent])). Yes, the question is about displaying the blank row when the respective month is selected and along with the dax measure (returns/spent). you can ignore the aggregation part.